# Flutter Wrap Builder

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, mobile

I have a list with over 5000 models and need to display them in a Wrap. But the widget Wrap creates all the elements at once and this has a very bad effect on performance is there any way to display them as a ListView.builder

my code:

```
final list = [];

Wrap(
  runSpacing: 12,
  spacing: 12,
  children: List.generate(
    list.length,
    (index) => CustomChip(List[index]),
  ),
),
```

this is what I want to get

https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6e/dc/db/6edcdbadfe6230efef35abc93bd689ab.png

Comment: I am thinking about UX, like wouldn't it be better to categorize the items? Or maybe it should be using search

Comment: The `Wrap.builder` or `builder`  for `Wrap` is not available yet, the feature request is already raised. Check [Request for Wrap.builder](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/87789)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gridview.builder or Add use Pagination, when t=you reached the maximum scroll then load another data and add into the list which you have used Wrap.

Comment: Yes I use Pagination but problem is that Wrap widget build all children at once

Comment: did you tried `GridView.builder` ?

Comment: my chips width is not fixed.